# Traverse through HTML DOM - Scraping HTML link

Tags: php, html, dom, web-scraping, domparser

I am trying to traverse through HTML URL link and I couldn't be able to find a better way to do it. I have referred many libraraies like simple php DOM parser and sympony crowler. But I couldn't adapt it to my problem easily.

I wanted to scrape some hotel data from a site and save into a database. HTML format will be following;

```
<ol class="listings infinite-scroll-enabled">
<li class="hotel sponsored" data-info="1|108447|Dual|MERCHANT||" data-pimms="AP57" data-title="Ramada Shreveport Airport" data-hotel-id="108447" data-accommodation-type="_ACC_TYPE_NAME@Hotel">
    <h1>hotel name</h1>
    <p>price</p>
    <div class="dcription">
        <p>Distance</p>
    </div>
 <li>
 <li class="hotel sponsored" data-info="1|108447|Dual|MERCHANT||" data-pimms="AP57" data-title="Ramada Shreveport Airport" data-hotel-id="108447" data-accommodation-type="_ACC_TYPE_NAME@Hotel">
    <h1>hotel name</h1>
    <p>price</p>
    <div class="dcription">
        <p>Distance</p>
    </div>
 <li>
 
 ..... etc
 <ol>
```

Actually I want to get all listing details inside

tag as a loop and get all detail like hotel name, description, distance.

So I used following queries and could be able get loop of

tag but I can traverse it again and get separate value for each.

```
<?php

 require 'sim/simple_html_dom.php'; 

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$url = "https://www.hotels.com/search.do?resolved-location=CITY%3A1505671%3AUNKNOWN%3AUNKNOWN&destination-id=1505671&q-destination=Shreveport,%20Louisiana,%20United%20States%20of%20America&q-check-in=2017-07-09&q-check-out=2017-07-10&q-rooms=1&q-room-0-adults=2&q-room-0-children=0";

// Load a file
$html->load_file($url);

$element = $html->find('ol > li');

foreach($element as $listItem){
    $listItem = $listItem->find('h3');
    
    echo $listItem->innertext;
}
```

Please let me know if there a best way to do. I went through many articles but couldn't find.

Thanks.

Comment: a best way to do? ... what's wrong with your approach?

Comment: Hi @ad_on_is, now in this way I am getting piece of <li> html as a inner text as followers;<li class="hotel sponsored" data-info="1|108447|Dual|MERCHANT||" data-pimms="AP57" data-title="Ramada Shreveport Airport" data-hotel-id="108447" data-accommodation-type="_ACC_TYPE_NAME@Hotel">
 <h1>hotel name</h1>
 <p>price</p>
 <div class="dcription">
  <p>Distance</p>
 </div>
 <li>.  but how can I go through again and separate all values inside <li> tag.